# Change the post URL based on author ID

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I want to implement custom post urls.

Currently the post urls are like this: **http://example.org/post-url/**

I want to do something like **http://example.org/_blog/_blog_post/post-url/**
I want to add the **/_blog/_blog_post/** before post url

If the author's ID is 7. The custom url will take effect on the blog posts url
if not, the post url will remain like this: **http://example.org/post-url/**

Here's my current code in functions.php

```
$args = get_user_by( 'id', 7 ); 
$wp_posts = get_posts($args);

if (count($wp_posts)) {
    global $wp_rewrite; 
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( $wp_rewrite->root . '/_blog_/internship_blog/%postname%/');
}
else {
    global $wp_rewrite; 
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( $wp_rewrite->root . '/%postname%/');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Rewrite endpoints API](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/),
I use this API to add a `/download/` after my post url.